# How do I list all the references of a given PowerShell module?

Tags: powershell

How to list all the modules that this given module depends upon? (Particularly, I need their names and versions)

Comment: Like `Get-Module`?

Comment: @Abraham Zinala no. I need only the dependencies of one single module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To find the *formally declared* module dependencies - if any - of a given module via its [module manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-modulemanifest) (`*.psd1`)**:

```
Get-Module $someModule -ListAvailable | ForEach-Object {
  $_.RequiredModules, $_.NestedModules.RequiredModules
}
```

- [`Get-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-module) returns [`System.Management.Automation.PSModuleInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSModuleInfo) instance(s) describing the specified module(s).
- `-ListAvailable` makes sure that modules that *aren't presently imported* but are *discoverable* via [auto-loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules#module-auto-loading), are included in the lookup.
- `$_.RequiredModules` lists the direct module dependencies, and `$_.NestedModules.RequiredModules` those of any *nested* modules (which is presumably rare).<sup>Tip of the hat to [Ash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9164015/ash).</sup>

Note that whether the information returned includes *version information* depends on whether a version is explicitly specified in the target module's manifest's `RequiredModules` entry.

---

**Caveat**: The above **will *not* discover *de facto* dependencies** that aren't also formally declared, based on the module's *runtime behavior*. **Discovering such dependencies would be both *nontrivial* and *brittle***.

That said, if ***interactive* discovery** is an option, use the following  as the first command *from a pristine session* started with `-NoProfile`, which may at least provide clues as to what dependent modules are de facto being imported *at import time*:

```
Import-Module -Verbose -Force $someModule
```

However, there could still be *additional* dependent modules that the module's *commands* import *on demand*, when they're first called.

[`Set-PSDebug`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-psdebug) with its `-Trace` parameter offers general tracing of code execution.

Comment: Thanks, @Ash - please see my update.